# Change shipping carrier name issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, shipping-methods

I need to change the shipping name displayed everywhere in Magento (both frontend and backend) for 2 stores. 
This is for backend order:

[image]

I need to change in transactional emails, checkout shipping step, invoice, etc. I found the template file for almost all of them. I can do the logic there.

`If store = X or store = Y display ABC instead of Shipping Option-testare_shipping`.

The fact is I don't wanna do that, I am looking for a more elegant solution. It is important that I'm not allowed to change the database :). If there any idea to do that, maybe with an observer? rewrite core functionality etc?

Thank you

Comment: Go into the backend of magento under system > configuration > sales > shipping methods. This should allow you to set carrier name and method title

Comment: As I said, I don't want to change the database :)